# how to make a list of tags justify right?

Tags: css, html-lists

I want a right-aligned list

```html
<ol>
  <li>Debian</li>
  <li>Ubuntu</li>
  <li>Mint</li>
  <li>elementaryOS</li>
  <li>RedHat</li>
  <li>Fedora</li>
  <li>Slackware</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: you don't align a list, you align the text: `li { text-align: right }`. Alternatively, if you need the list bullet on the right side: `ol { direction: rtl; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using css and adding the `text-align: right;` property. To have the bullets follow, we need them to follow the text and being set to inside. That is done with `list-style-position: inside;`

```css
ol, ul
{
    text-align: right;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<ol> 
  <li>Debian 
    <ul> 
      <li>Ubuntu</li> 
      <li>Mint</li> 
      <li>elementaryOS</li>
    </ul> 
   </li> 
   <li> RedHat 
    <ul> 
      <li>Fedora</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Slackware</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

try:
li{
float:right
}
in your css stylesheet

Comment: `float` is not a property to align elements. `float` is for floating an element within a text-block such as images in a newspaper. For everything else you other tools such as flexbox and grid.